# UIbutton label property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, uibutton

Just start to using Xcode. I made an IBOutlet from UIButton to have a possibility to change title with changing a localization setting. I try this code to do this

```
_loginButton.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Login", nil);
```

But this code does not set the button title. Do I need to use another kind of property?

Thank you very much for answering!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a `UIControlState` to set the title for.

```
[_loginButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Login", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

For UIButton, try setting the title like this:

```
[self.loginButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Login", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

There are other states as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

But if you don't specify the title for those states, they will use the normal state by default.